# Using piping with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I want pipe the output of one command to another. Command 2 has to be run after the command 1 execution is completed and so on. I tried using 'wait' of 'subprocess.Popen()'. But somehow it is not working.

Can someone help me on this?

Code used:

```
proc= subprocess.Popen(['python27','scriptA.py',file],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.wait()
sortedop= subprocess.Popen(['sort'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=proc.stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
sortedop.wait()
countReducer= subprocess.Popen(['python27', 'scriptB.py'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=sortedop.stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
countReducer.wait()
fd = open(file+".json", 'w')
countpostprocesser= subprocess.Popen(['python27', 'scriptC.py'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=fd,stdin=countReducer.stdout,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
countpostprocesser.wait()
fd.close()
```

Comment: What isn't working, exactly?

Comment: I want to give output of 'Script.py' to the 'sort' command but only after scriptA.py has been completed the execution. For that I used *.wait() but this is not working.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're saying isn't working. Is the output of `script.py` not making it to `sort`, or is it going to `sort` before `script.py` completes?

Comment: Are you purposely using `subprocess.call` for executing `scriptA.py`? That doesn't return a `Popen` object, it just returns the exit code of the process it ran. So you could will fail as soon as you call `proc.wait()`, since `proc` will be an `int`. It also [isn't safe to use `subprocess.call` with `stdout`/`stdin` set to `subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

Comment: If your pipe buffer is full the executed program will block until it can write to the buffer again. If you don't read from the pipe but call `wait` you have a deadlock.

Comment: If I remove the 'wait' statements, the code is working fine. But sometimes it gives weird results as the first command has not completed the execution and second command tries to consume its output. So yes, it going to sort before script.py completes.

Comment: You really want to wait for one command to complete before starting the next one? Pipelines are usually run in parallel with the stdout of one used as the stdin of the next.

Comment: @dano, it was typo. I am using Popen.

Comment: @ mata..yeah, it is deadlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want one script to complete before the next one starts and the output data isn't too large, you can read the data into memory:

```
proc= subprocess.Popen(['python27','scriptA.py',file],cwd="C:\\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
sortedop= subprocess.Popen(['sort'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out, err = sortedop.communicate(out)
countReducer= subprocess.Popen(['python27', 'scriptB.py'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out, err = countReducer.communicate(out)
fd = open(file+".json", 'w')
countpostprocesser= subprocess.Popen(['python27', 'scriptC.py'],cwd="C:\pythonPrograms\\",stdout=fd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out, err = countpostprocesser.communicate(out)
```

Comment: I tried with above code. But surprisingly 'sortedop' is not taking the output of 'proc'. But I am able to print the output of 'proc'.

Comment: @codelearner - may be my bad... I used the wrong stdin for sortedop (it should be subprocess.PIPE). I've made the edit.